Express the inf of a functional via Rayleigh quotient
Let $\Omega$ be an open and bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^N$, with $N \geq 3$. Take $p \in\left(2,2^*=\frac{2 N}{N-2}\right]$ and define
$$
S_p=\inf _{\substack{u \in H_0^1(\Omega) \\ u \neq 0}} \frac{\int_{\Omega}|\nabla u|^2 d x}{\left(\int_{\Omega}|u|^p d x\right)^{2 / p}}
$$
This number is positive by the Sobolev embedding Theorem . Consider the functional $I: H_0^1(\Omega) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$
I(u)=\frac{1}{2} \int_{\Omega}|\nabla u|^2 d x-\frac{1}{p} \int_{\Omega}|u|^p d x
$$
and let $\mathcal{N}$ be the Nehari manifold associated to $I$. Prove that
$$
\inf _{u \in \mathcal{N}} I(u)=\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{p}\right) S_p^{\frac{p}{p-2}}
$$
I want to take a derivative of this quotient and I turn to this post LINK, but I think he forget the
$\left(\int_{\Omega_t}|u|^q d x\right)^{2 / q}$Denominator of the laplace term, and I don't know how to start this problem
